# How to add real numbers in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to do this addition

```
time_count_real <= time_count_real + 0.000_000_02 ;
```

but i faced this error

```
cannot synthesize non-constant real objects or values
```

so how can i add real numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For synthesis, you need to represent the real number in a binary format (fixed-point or floating point, depending on what range you want). [VHDL-2008 provides a few packages](http://vhdl.org/fphdl/index.html) with conversion functions to make this easier. For instance, if you're using floating point:

```
use ieee.float_pkg.all;

...

signal float_real  : real;
signal float_bin32 : float32;
signal float_slv   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal float_sum   : float32;

...

float_bin32 <= to_float(float_real);

float_sum <= float_bin32 + 0.002;

float_slv <= to_slv(float_sum);
```

Note that the last statement doesn't convert the value; it's just an example of casting the float32 type into a std_logic_vector.

Comment: Note that the VHDL packages can also be synthesised by VHDL-93 tools